# React application is not saving changes when i edit them in Visual Studios

Tags: reactjs, web-applications, electron

For some reason none of the edits I make to the the html/css of my react application are wanting to save. Before they would auto save but now nothing happens even with closing the application and restarting it? I did some research and tried adding this to the electron.js section

```
require('electron-reload')(__dirname, {
 electron: require(`${__dirname}/node_modules/electron`)
});
```

If there is something you can do to help I would greatly appreciate it

Comment: Note I formatted the code properly, it did not want to be inserted in my post properly though

Comment: how did you create the react application? sounds like you are using webpack or some kind of bundler, and you are missing the re-bundling step, so you are not seeing the changes that you are making on the source-code

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by make edits. Please elaborate. Do you mean saving the edits? Are you using an IDE? Did you try CTRL + S? If you mean unable to see changes in the browser, try hard refreshing with CTRL + SHIFT + R